# Unable to update document without specify Primary Key

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

schema.py:

```
class Test(Document):
    _id = StringField()
    classID = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    status = StringField()
```

====================

database.py:

```
query = schema.Test(_id = id)
query.update(status = "confirm")
```

***Critical error occured. attempt to update a document not yet saved***

I can update the DB only if I specify _id = StringField(primary_key=True), but if I insert a new data, the _id has to be inserted by me instead of automatically created by MongoDB.

Anyone can help me with a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inserts and updates are distinct operations in MongoDB:

- Insert adds a document to the collection
- Update finds a document in the collection given a search criteria, then changes this document

If you haven't inserted a document, trying to update it won't do anything since it will never be found by any search criteria. Your ODM is pointing this out to you and prevents you from updating a document you haven't saved. Using the driver you can issue the update anyway but it won't have any effect.

If you want to add a new document to the database, use inserts. To change documents that are already saved, use updates. To change fields on document instances without saving them, consult your ODM documentation to figure out how to do that instead of attempting to save the documents.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I have inserted the document. I inserted documents without any values on _id (hence the _id will be generated automatically by MongoDB) and I didn't specify the _id field as a primary key. Therefore the issue appeared. When I called the db container and use _id -->  (query = schema.Test(_id = id) --> presumably is a PK to update other fields, it showed the above error. 
If I specified the _id as a PK in the beginning, it asked me to insert value of _id. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Not too much. MongoDB does not have the concept of primary keys. Add some documentation references to the question explaining what the update method does.